# Loading local file using Cloud Functions to BigQuery returns OSError: [Errno 30] `Read-only file system:

Tags: google-bigquery, google-cloud-functions

I am trying to load a Dataframe into BigQuery. I do this as follows:

```
# Prepare temp file to stream from local file
temp_file = table_name + '-' + str(timestamp_in_ms())
df.to_csv(temp_file, index=None, header=True)

# Define job_config
job_config = bigquery.LoadJobConfig()
job_config.schema = schema
job_config.skip_leading_rows = 1
job_config.source_format = bigquery.SourceFormat.CSV

# Create job to load data into table
with open(temp_file, "r+b") as source_file:
    load_job = client.load_table_from_file(source_file, dataset_ref.table(table_name), job_config=job_config)
```

This works fine in local development, however when I deploy the Cloud Function it returns the following error:

OSError: [Errno 30] `Read-only file system: '{temp_file}'`

This happens on the line with `open(temp_file, "r+b") as source_file:`

Why can it not read local files on the Cloud Function temporary storage? What went wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably you didn't specified the folder /tmp

Local Disk

> Cloud Functions provides access to a local disk mount point (/tmp)
>   which is known as a "tmpfs" volume in which data written to the volume
>   is stored in memory. There is no specific fee associated with this
>   however writing data to the /tmp mountpoint will consume memory
>   resources provisioned for the function.

As explained on: https://cloud.google.com/functions/pricing

Comment: The only difficulty is when you are testing it locally, you need to do `tmp/` instead of `/tmp`.